# Unity Dependency Injection - Method with Generic Repository return type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, repository, unity-container

I am having trouble figuring out how to get Unity to work with my generic repository. Here is my basic setup:

```
public static Repository<IEntity> GetRepository()
{
     //This is of type CustomerRepository
     return unitOfWork.CustomerRepository;         
}


CustomerRepository  : Repository<Customer>, ICustomerRepository
Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity

ICustomerRepository : IRepository<Customer>
IRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable where TEntity : class, IEntity

Customer : IEntity
```

The error on return unitOfWork.CustomerRepository is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'CustomerRepository' to 'Repository'

I'm totally lost, I have tried so many ways of registering it that I am starting to think I need to do something else to achieve what I want... No idea what I am doing with the RegisterTypes at this point, as you can see:

```
container.RegisterType<IEntity, Customer>();
container.RegisterType(typeof(Repository<Customer>), typeof(CustomerRepository));
container.RegisterType(typeof(CustomerRepository), typeof(Repository<Customer>));

container.RegisterType(typeof(Repository<IEntity>), typeof(Repository<Customer>));
container.RegisterType(typeof(Repository<Customer>), typeof(Repository<IEntity>));


container.RegisterType(typeof(Repository<>), typeof(Repository<IEntity>));
container.RegisterType(typeof(Repository<IEntity>), typeof(Repository<>));

            //---------

container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<Customer>), typeof(Repository<IEntity>));
container.RegisterType<IRepository<Customer>, CustomerRepository>();
container.RegisterType(typeof(Repository<IEntity>), typeof(CustomerRepository));


            //--------------------
container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
container.RegisterType<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();

container.RegisterType<IRepository<Customer>, ICustomerRepository>();
container.RegisterType<Repository<Customer>, CustomerRepository>();
container.RegisterType<IRepository<Customer>, CustomerRepository>();

container.RegisterType<IRepository<Customer>, ICustomerRepository>();
container.RegisterType<Repository<Customer>, CustomerRepository>();
container.RegisterType<IRepository<Customer>, CustomerRepository>();

container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<IEntity>), typeof(IRepository<Customer>));
```

None of these ways of registering it are helping.

**EDIT 1:**

How can I get this to work?:

```
public static Repository<TEntity> GetRepository<TEntity>(string entityName, string conectionName) where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
     var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(connectionName);

     switch(entityName){
     case "Customer":
           return unitOfWork.CustomerRepository;
     }

     return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, and break down your code in more lines, you are doing this:

```
public static Repository<IEntity> GetRepository()
{
    CustomerRepository repository1 = unitOfWork.CustomerRepository;
    Repository<IEntity> repository2 = repository1;
    return repository2;
}
```

So indirectly you are assiging a value of type `CustomerRepository` to type `Repository<IEntity>`, which will not work, since `Repository<IEntity>` is not a base type of `CustomerRepository`. On the other hand, type `Repository<Customer>` is the base class of `CustomerRepository`, so assigning `CustomerRepository` to `Repository<Customer>` will work.

*** EDIT ***

Based on your comments, some new insights:

```
public static Repository<TEntity> GetRepository<TEntity>()
    where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    if (typeof(TEntity) == typeof(Customer))
        return (Repository<TEntity>)(object)new Repository<Customer>();
    if (typeof(TEntity) == typeof(Product))
        return (Repository<TEntity>)(object)new Repository<Product>();
    throw new Exception("Entity of type " + typeof(IEntity).Name + " is not supported.");
}
```

Or... using reflection (slower):

```
public static Repository<TEntity> GetRepository<TEntity>()
    where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    Type repositoryType = typeof(Repository<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TEntity));
    return (Repository<TEntity>)Activator.CreateInstance(repositoryType);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is pretty much what I am doing, but I need the return type for the method to be generic. I thought I could achieve this with dependency injection but I guess not?

I have also tried this:
`public static Repository<TEntity> GetRepository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class, IEntity`


where the return statement is: 
`Repository<Customer> repository2 = repository1;`

Basically I want to get a certain repository based on the parameters and use it generically. Do you know if this is the right direction or how I can achieve this with Unity??

Comment: Two seperate questions: 1. Have you considered making IRepository<T> covariant? 2. I guess you only want to return `CustomerRepository ` if `TEntity` is set to `Customer`. Why, in your example, do you always return `CustomerRepository`?

Comment: It is simplified down, for example if I had `TEntity` as `Customer`, I want `CustomerRepository`. If I had `TEntity` as `Product`, I want `ProductRepository`. I just took out all of the irrelevant stuff to not distract from my real issue. What do you mean by `IRepository<T>` covariant?

Comment: About co- en contra-variance, please read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I just updated my answer. Perhapse one of my two suggestion can work for you.

Comment: Instead of returning a Repository<Customer>, I need a CustomerRepository which has additional functionality.

Also my Repository<T> takes a context object in its constructor, which is assigned in my UnitOfWork class based on a connectionName string, so I am not sure how I would do that in your example. 

see edit above.

Comment: If you have *specific* code in *specific* classes, you cannot use a *generic* solution like reflection.

Comment: I don't really need that specific code, but my repository is set up as that specific class. I only want to use the generic class's code... So I just want to convert my `CustomerRepository` to `Repository<Customer>` , and have that be an acceptable return type for my `public Repository<TEntity> GetRepository<TEntity>()` method. Can that work?

Comment: Anyway, I've tried calling `GetRepository<IEntity>()` , and returning a `Repository<Customer>`, but it is saying it cannot convert between those. Even though `Customer` is an `IEntity`, and I am just assuming I have the unity mappings set up correctly... Shouldnt this work at least? Forget the specific version, `CustomerRepository`

Comment: First: I adjusted my answer a bit. Second: If you call `GetRepository` WITHOUT any generic arguments, what repository do you expect? Why that one? And how is your program to know that?

Comment: I just want to say thank you Martin for helping me with this.

So what do you mean by calling it without generic arguments? I'm not sure I understand your question

Comment: Lets take one step back. In your first examle you have the method `Repository<IEntity> GetRepository()`. Why should this method return `Repository<Customer>`. Why not `Repository<Product>`? You are using an interface `IEntity`. I assume you are using that to have multuple implementations, like `Customer` and `Product`. Same thing goes for the Repositories, there will be multiple repositories. Why does your method ONLE return `Repository<Customer>` and why not another? And if it should return multiple repositories... how is the method supposed to know?